# Increment the year by 1 if month is December

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

I passed the  year and month separately  as parameters in pentaho and add month by 1 and convert to date format. I wrote like this to join year, month and date.

```
('${year}' || '-' || '${month}'+1 || '-' || 1 )::date
```

I need to increase the month by 1 from existing date. if the month is December(12) , new date month will be 1 (January) and year will be the next year. 
ex: 2012-12-30 new date will be 2013-01-30  

How to write a query for this  in postgreSQl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the month *after* converting it to a date:

```
('${year}' || '-' || '${month}' || '-' || 1 )::date + interval '1' month
```

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql provides with multiple [date/time functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html). In order to increase your date by 1 month, you would need to use the `interval` operator. Like mentioned in *above answer*, you would require to first change your parameters to a **date field** and then **add** `interval '1' month`. This will fetch you the desired result.

You can also try using Pentaho **Calculator** Step to also increase the date by 1 month. Check the below image.

[image]

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/646494ad19c8c58e404a) of the above ktr.

Hope it helps :)